# Attach fancybox to a link inside the fancybox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

I would like to know a way to load my fancybox and to attach a fancybox to one of the link in this fancybox. I'm using since today the last version of fancybox (2.0.1).

Here is what I tried without success:

```
    $('a.new_category_link').fancybox({
        closeClick: false,
        afterShow:  function() {
            $('a.edit_category_link').fancybox({
                closeClick: false
            });
        }
    });
```

As required with version 2.0.1, my link with class "edit_category_link" has also the class "fancybox.ajax".

For the people used to the oldest version, `hideOnContentClick` was replaced by `closeClick` and `onComplete` by `afterShow`.

Right now, when i click on `a.edit_category_link` loaded in my fancybox, it renders the page in html in the parent page, not the fancybox.

If you have an idea, please don't hesitate to share it!

Comment: Why don't you link to some controller action than in response render another fancybox? For an user it will look like reopening the fancybox, but with different content.

Comment: @socjopata Thx for idea, I tried already to do that by having this in my edit.js.erb file : `$.fancybox( {href : '/categories/<%= @category %>/edit', type: 'ajax'} );` and it was always reopening the first fancybox. Do you have some clue in the same direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fancyBox since v2 is using "live" to handle clicks, so you my try like this -

```
$('a.new_category_link, a.edit_category_link').fancybox({
    closeClick: false
});
```

Comment: That did the trick, btw that's really nice and comfortable to be able attaching every fancybox at once even before that the content is displayed.