# Cant open images with Fancybox after appending to Flexslider after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, fancybox, coffeescript, flexslider, woothemes

The following code below is in CoffeeScript and after a couple of hours playing around with it and finally reading the documentation on WooThemes, I was able to get the Flexslider to append images correctly after clicking on my button to load the rest of the images from Instagram.

However, now when I click on the image, it isn't opening the Fancybox like the rest of the images that load on page load and was wondering if I could get some help here.

```
Slider =
  flexi: ->
    $('.flexslider').flexslider
      animation: 'slide'
      animationLoop: true
      slideshow: false
      itemWidth: 160
      itemMargin: 5
      minItems: 1
      maxItems: 10
      start: (slider) ->
        $('#load-more').on 'click', (event) ->
          event.preventDefault()
          $.ajax
            type: 'get'
            url: $(this).find('a').attr('href')
            dataType: 'jsonp'
            success: (data) ->
              $.each data.data, (index, value) ->
                slider.addSlide '<li class="thumb" data-profile="' + value.user.profile_picture + '" data-lat="0" data-long="0" data-id="' + value.id + '" data-thumb="' + value.images.thumbnail.url + '" data-username="' + value.user.username + '" data-comments="' + value.comments.count + '" data-likes="' + value.likes.count + '" data-text="' + value.caption.text + '" data-link="' + value.link + '"><a href="' + value.images.low_resolution.url + '" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"><img alt="' + value.images.thumbnail.url.split('/')[3].split('.jpg')[0] + '" src="' + value.images.thumbnail.url + '" /></a></li>'

Fancy =
  box: (lat, lng, pid) ->
    street = undefined
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng lat, lng
    view = new google.maps.StreetViewService()
    $('.fancybox').fancybox
      width: 1155
      height: '95%'
      maxWidth: '95%'
      maxHeight: '95%'
      openEffect: 'none'
      autoSize: true
      autoResize:  false
      closeEffect: 'fade'
      scrolling: 'auto'
      type: 'iframe'
      helpers:
        media:{}

      beforeShow: ->
        ........
```

Comment: Which code is supposed to trigger the FancyBox? Is it the $('#load-more').on... ?

Comment: @DennisRongo : I bet is a link with `class="fancybox"`

Comment: try initializing fancybox before flexslider. Also, if you are just showing images you don't need to add the special class `fancybox.iframe` to the selector `.fancybox`

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the fancybox call with live() or on() or go and change the FancyBox source code to use the live() instead of regular bind() method. Here's sort of an untested code to give you a sense.

// on

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.fancybox', function() {
    $(this).fancybox({ /* options */ }).trigger('click');
    return false;
}
```

// live

```
$('.fancybox').live('click', function() {
    $(this).fancybox({ /* options */ }).trigger('click');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The OP seems to be using fancybox v2.x, which already uses `live` to support present or dynamically added elements so I don't think this will solve their issue.

Comment: Are you sure cause I'm not seeing it? https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js

Comment: Pretty sure ;) ....hear it from the developer's own voice http://stackoverflow.com/a/8271292/1055987

Comment: OK, well still not sure where Fancy is being declared so it probably needs to be moved out of that function where it is now.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate all the responses guys. Dennis, JFK, you are awesome. If I had more reputatation, I would upvote these but cannot. I've only been a member for a couple of weeks now. Ayways, onto the post. Dennis, your solution did the trick.

    $('.fancybox').on 'click', ->
      $(this).fancybox
        ......

Comment: Great! I figured if you had version 2, it should have been working to begin with :). Glad it helped.

Comment: Hi! I'am using previous stable version of Fancybox, but this is causing me some problems. Seems like .trigger('click') is breaking my page, on Chrome displaying "Aw Snap!" frame. If there is come other trick, what might help, I would appreciate any help. Thanks! PS, using v1.7.2 of jQuery, but thinking to update, so .live function won't be available any more.